# ASP.NET app never starts

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-6

After migrating my app to .NET 4 it's not starting. When i'm trying to load it in browser it endlessly loading it and nothing else happening. There is no errors or timeouts, just loading.

Please help. What should i do? What reasons there might be? I'm using IIS6 btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some weird combination of IIS restarts, site stops and appPool recycles everything began to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Did you register .NET 4 with IIS? Do you need to call aspnet_regiis.exe from the 4.0 directory?

Are you sure the app is using the correct Application Pool? Is the pool set to .NET 4? Is it integrated?

What does your web.config look like? Does the compilation node contain `targetFramework="4.0"`? Are you referencing 4.0 versions of the assemblies you need?

Unfortunately there is a ton of places to look into.

Comment: Just run aspnet_regiis -u aspnet_regiis -u it doesn't help. AppPool is right, but i don't know how to check if it is integrated in IIS6. All web.config stuff seems to be ok.

Comment: i mean aspnet_regiis -u aspnet_regiis -i sorry